# Export from database to a specific pdf file in php

Tags: php, html

Hello guys i wanna know if is possible to fill out a specific PDF file with some information from database. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible: [PHP PDF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php). There are various [other](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php%20to%20pdf&aq=0&oq=php%20to%20pdf&aqs=chrome.0.0j57j0j62l2j64.3625&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) libraries for it as well.